# Vulkan pSurfaceFormatCount is zero with NVIDIA drivers

Tags: drivers, nvidia, xorg, xserver, vulkan

I don't know if it was an update or a package I installed but all Vulkan applications are no longer working. OpenGL apps are working though.

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 with Gnome 3. I have a GTX 950M and I've changed between graphics drivers in 'Sofware & Updates', 'Additional Drivers' tab. I've tried different open source drivers, like nvidia-driver-430 / 440 / 410. None worked.

In some apps I get this error:

```
X Error of failed request:  BadDrawable (invalid Pixmap or Window parameter)
  Major opcode of failed request:  149 ()
  Minor opcode of failed request:  4
  Resource id in failed request:  0x220000d
  Serial number of failed request:  179
  Current serial number in output stream:  184
```

Others simply don't display anything (maybe due to error handling).
Offscreen Vulkan rendering is working. I know this because one of my apps uses it and displays logs.
The windowing system (GLFW3) is working in OpenGL apps, while in Vulkan the window opens but it remains black or crashes with the above error.

I remember that lately I've installed some packages for a program I wanted to run, like sld2, qt5, and maybe others that I don't remember. I've since purged them.

I honestly have no idea what could be wrong. If you have any ideas please share or if you need more info I can provide.

EDIT:
I've tried these common workarounds but they didn't work:
QT_X11_NO_MITSHM=1
LIBOVERLAY_SCROLLBAR=0

EDIT2:
I've tried using the proprietary 435 driver but it didn't work.

EDIT3:
Thanks to @kvark and further debugging, I've narrowed it down a bit. The origin of the issue is that the `pSurfaceFormatCount` is 0 when querying with `vkGetPhysicalDeviceSurfaceFormatsKHR`. I'm currently running the 440 driver and my application recognizes the Nvidia GPU. There are no messages from the validation layers.

Answer (score 3):

I've had this issue on an Nvidia-equipped laptop. The problem and a workaround are nicely described here - https://dev.getsol.us/T6335

Basically, you can work around this by forcing NVidia Vulkan ICD with the environment variable set from one of the startup scripts:

```
VK_ICD_FILENAMES=/usr/share/vulkan/icd.d/10_nvidia.json
```

Your path to the NV ICD may be different (link is for Solus, while this question is about Ubuntu).

Comment: I finally had time to check out the answer and I have to say that in that directory I don't have a '10_nvidia.json' file. In also in a laptop with an nvidia GPU with a intel CPU. I have 4 files: 'intel_icd.x86_64.json', 'nvidia_layers.json', 'nvidia_icd.json' and 'radeon_icd.x86_64.json'. Which one should I link to the VK_ICD_FILENAMES variable? Also, in which file should I add it to?

Comment: Well, exporting VK_ICD_FILENAMES to equal the path to 'nvidia_icd.json' has fixed some issues. However, the vkGetPhysicalDeviceSurfaceFormatsKHR function returns me 0 formats available. I'll edit the question.

Comment: This doesn't match the spec: "The number of format pairs supported must be greater than or equal to 1. pSurfaceFormats must not contain an entry whose value for format is VK_FORMAT_UNDEFINED."

So it's a conformance issue with NV driver?.. Might be worth double-checking that you have all the Vulkan packages installed.